# Anybody know software to record one side of a SIP telephone conversation?

Tags: audio-recording, recording

Using a SIP softphone with plugin, or sip voip hardphone, I'd like to record only my side of the conversation.  Does anyone know open source or even paid software to do exactly this?

Comment: I'm using a PBX SIP system.  A hardware recorders would split the packets and just record those packets, so essentially I'd need to just ignore the incoming (or outgoing, depending on which side I'm recording) packets.  I just dont know of a hardware device that does this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about recording telephone calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you are recording only your side of the conversation, I.E, your voice, I would just use a sepearte microphone and recording software. If you cannot do that, I would imagine you could use something like jack or soundcloud to create virtual audio routes through your computer.

It would be helpful to get a little more detail on your setup. What softphone/hardphone are you using and what computer OS are you running.